# Why Sqlite3 Python library is giving different result of Group by Query than the original one?

Tags: python, sqlite, group-by

I am having a weird issue. I am using Sqlite for storing Stock data and a native `sqlite3` library to interact with it. When I run on TablePlus it returns the following:

[image]

But when I run the code it returns the following:

[image]

I am unable to figure out why is it happening. The count is correct but it is pulling the wrong symbols.

The code that is doing all this is given below:

```
def fetch_data_by_date(day):
    results = None
    conn = get_connection()
    print(day)

    sql = "select DISTINCT(created_at), symbol,count(stock_id) as total from mentions" \
          " inner join symbols on symbols.id = mentions.stock_id WHERE DATE(created_at) = '{}'" \
          " group by symbol order by total DESC LIMIT 5".format(day)

    print(sql)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
```

Comment: Timestamps seem different too.

Comment: @user56700 you are right. But the count is correct and I checked for multiple date. Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like there are more than 4 stocks with total=1 and it orders them in different order (and select just 4 of them). Try `ORDER BY total, symbol DESC LIMIT 5`.

Comment: It must be the way sqlite3 interprets vs the TablePlus client. Have you tried to just select all and look at the data to compare it? Or maybe it's too much?

Comment: If there are too many entries with total=1 Sqlite is free to choose the order in this subgroup. Different versions may do it differently. To test, you may also order by full "created_at" or by "symbol".

Comment: @MichaelButscher you are right. `Order by created_at` returns the identical results. Now what should I do? If you say is right than how a library is changing the result?

Comment: The library is not changing the results. If the conditions that you provide in the ORDER BY clause can't sort in a unique way the rows, then you get undefined results. Extend the conditions, like Buran proposed to: `ORDER BY total DESC, symbol`

Comment: @forpas now the results are identical but not correct. It is only fetching records having total = 1

Comment: Did you put DESC after total?

Comment: @forpas Yes I did, it is now omitting `AMD` from the results as it it slides down.

Comment: Create a fiddle with sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 so I can test it.

Comment: @forpas is right that you must have `DESC` after `total`, not like I suggested - after symbol - my bad.

Comment: Also the value of created_at in your results is undefined and could vary.

Comment: @forpas `select symbol,count(stock_id) as total from mentions inner join symbols on symbols.id = mentions.stock_id WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2021-08-02' group by symbol HAVING total > 0 ORDER BY total DESC ,symbol LIMIT 5` finally works!

Thanks guys!

Comment: `HAVING total > 0` is not needed. `total` can't be 0 because you use mentions.stock_id in the ON clause, so it can't be null.